# How to customize static_placeholder html code in django cms

Tags: django, django-cms

I want to customise the `HTML` for `static_placeholder`.

Html Code:

```
<ul class="top_list">
  <li class="spc"><span class="ion-ios-telephone"></span> Call us: {% static_placeholder 'call_us' %}</li>
  <li class="spc"><span class="ion-android-mail"></span> Mail us: <a href="mailto:{% static_placeholder 'mail_us' %}">{% static_placeholder 'mail_us' %}</a>
  </li>   
</ul>

<div class="cms-plugin cms-plugin-1"><p>+91-95578XXXXX</p></div>
```

this what cms is rendering as the theme is expecting `<span>` and cms is rendering `<div>` layout is distorted .

Comment: Can you elaborate about what exactly is happening right now and what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1):

This seems as a snapshot from the edit mode, when the CMS inserts `<div>` tags around content to enable front-end editing.

As a first step, publish the page and preview as anonymous user (log out or use incognito mode). If the problem is no longer there, then it was due to the editor.

I would recommend designing the CSS in a way that it is not thrown off by insertion of the `<div>` tags, however, if this poses a large problem you may remove `{% cms_toolbar %}` from your template - however, this then removes your ability to edit the page.